# Expresso Store: "No items are on sale"

Tags: expresso-store, stash

Searching for all items that are on sale, as of Express Store 2.0.4, is currently MIA, despite the presence of the `search:on_sale` parameter in the [docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/search_tag.html). That is, this code...

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" search:on_sale="yes"}
    {title}
{/exp:store:search}
```

... returns all items in the products channel, not just products on sale.

You can hack around this by using looping through all products and checking each one using the `on_sale` conditional:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" disable="member_data|pagination" limit="99"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
            {if on_sale}
                {title}
            {/if}
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But has anyone figured out how to display a *Sorry, no items are currently on sale message* when no items are on sale? I've tried a PHP (input), PHP (output), and a variety of Stash syntax. Something very strange is happening either with parse order or the way that `on_sale` works. For example, you would think this would work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" disable="member_data|pagination" limit="99"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}

            {if on_sale}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="sale_items_exist" value="true"}
                {title}
            {/if}

    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}


{if "{exp:stash:get name='sale_items_exist' process='end'}" != "true"}
    <p>Sorry, no items are currently on sale</p>
{/if}

<p>Debug: the stash variable is {exp:stash:get name='sale_items_exist' process='end'}</p>
```

When I use that code, if there *is* an item on sale, that last line outputs nothing (and so my "no items on sale" message shows up even though it shouldn't). Somehow Stash is not setting `sale_items_exist` to `true`.

Has anyone solved this problem some other way?

Answer (score 3):

Another wild idea if you can't figure it out with parse order. Use Javascript!

```
if ($(".product-list-item").size() == 0) {
    $(".product-no-items").show();
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but if you're up against a deadline then it will certainly work.

Comment: Good enough for rock and roll / government work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill (and someone better at parse order than me may have a better solution), but you should be able to put no items bit inside an embed. That's my usual solution to get around parse order problems.

```
{embed="shared/no_items" items_exist="{exp:stash:get name='sale_items_exist' process='end'}"}
```

Then in your `shared/no_items` template:

```
{if "{embed:items_exist}" != "true"}
    <p>Sorry, no items are currently on sale</p>
{/if}
```

Like I said, there's probably a cleaner way around this, but I usually find parse order issues like this are just trial and error until you find something that works.

Comment: Makes sense, but unfortunately/amazingly stash is setting `sale_items_exist` to "true" even though every item in the loop must be be returning `false` for the `on_sale` conditional. In other words, if I just put `stash is showing {embed:items_exist}` inside `shared/no_items`, it outputs "true" even when I've disabled my sales. 

Is there possible there's something funky with the `on_sale` implementation?